# Restrict users under a question ban from chat

Tags: feature-request, chat, post-ban

Lounge<‌C++> frequently answers questions that are appropriate for the main site, and drive-by asking is a persistent problem. Lately there has been an increase in people coming to the room because they were [banned from asking questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers) on the main site. Likely they find the chatroom by Googling the answerers they found helpful.

Would it be difficult to require such users to ask a room owner for permission? Already some rooms are restricted, this feature would just extend that to blacklisted users. Perhaps it should be opt-in or perhaps not.

Comment: You mean people that are under question bans, right?  And not actual suspensions?  I misunderstood your request at first, because suspended users only have 1 rep (so they already can't chat).

Comment: @jadarnel27 I don't know the specifics of the policy by heart. If someone cannot ask a question on the main site at the moment, they shouldn't be using chat as a fallback.

Comment: Great, just making sure I understood =)  I edited slightly to clarify that point for people that are silly and pedantic like myself.

Comment: don't hold your breath on this one, we've been asking for a way for mods to know that a user is q-banned forever, and SE refuses every time. Your feature would reveal that the user is q-banned - no other reason someone would be asking for permission on a public room - and I don't think SE will let regular users know something they don't let moderators know.

Comment: @YannisRizos That's unfortunate =/  Could you link to one of those discussions?  I can't seem to find them with my search skills right now.

Comment: @jadarnel27 Can't share links, sorry, super secret stuff...

Comment: In PHP chat we've also seen in influx of users that are banned from asking questions.

Comment: Don’t you mean “frequently answers questions that are ***not*** appropriate for the main site”, or some such similar circumlocution?

Comment: No answer drawing from credible and/or official sources anyone??

Comment: @tchrist I mean exactly what I say.

Comment: Perhaps the bar could be raised from 20 reputation to 500 (or some other level, 100?) for question banned users. This would allow some good faith towards the user while still keeping out users who barely squeak past the 20 reputation while hitting the ban.

Comment: _"Lounge<‌C++> frequently answers questions that are appropriate for the main site, and drive-by asking is a persistent problem"_ No longer true at all, but I'm told it is in other rooms.

Comment: Well, this happens to us all the time, even when we are in the middle of discussing it happening to us... http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/22125204#22125204

Comment: @Yannis - What if the reputation requirement were simply raised. This would not let anyone know they were q-banned because it would just look like they were lurking as opposed to posting - which happens all the time anyway.

Answer (score 16):

I agree with this in the fact that users banned from asking questions on main should also be banned from posting messages in the chat.

This would prevent users from knowing who is question banned which seems to be a no-no when looking at [Yannis' comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137262/restrict-users-under-a-question-ban-from-chat#comment384181_137262):

> don't hold your breath on this one, we've been asking for a way for mods to know that a user is q-banned forever, and SE refuses every time. Your feature would reveal that the user is q-banned - no other reason someone would be asking for permission on a public room - and I don't think SE will let regular users know something they don't let moderators know.

And at the same time will prevent people banned from asking question on main to start "bugging" the room owners.

Often we see people who are banned on main come over to the chat and keep asking their (often terrible) questions there. This doesn't sound like the general idea behind the question bans.

Comment: For what it's worth, a user going that route will often divulge that they are q banned anyway. As for completely banning a user from chat, of course there are other reasons they might be visiting the chatroom. Maybe best to allow a q banned user if they have visited that room (or any room) before.

Comment: It is not hard to tell if someone is q-banned. Look at their question in chat, look at their 12 questions on their main account (most of which are negative), make an easy conclusion.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with this proposal. We already have enough problems with drive-by linkers, and this situation just exacerbates it. If you're question banned from Stack Exchange, that should mean question banned from Stack Exchange- not just the places where you're *supposed* to ask questions.